# Modelagem de estoque visando performance no Oracle e sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, oracle, desempenho

Uma tabela de estoque que será muito acessada onde terei o campo quantidade sendo constantemente alterado com entradas e saídas o que é mais indicado na questão de tunning e performance?

1- Minha tabela de estoque possuir uma linha por produto e a cada atualização de estoque eu fazer um update na qtd?

Ou

2- minha tabela de estoque possuir o campo id do produto e qtd. Ao invés de fazer um update na qtd eu teria um relacionamento com uma tabela de movimento diário de estoque e seriam feitos inserts da qtd de entrada com vlr positivo e  a saída com vlr negativo.

Todas as minhas consultas fariam.join entre as 2 tabelas somando a qtd de estoque da tabela de estoque com o sum da qtd movimentado diario
No fim do dia um processo seria rodado onde faria um update na qtd de estoque apagando os dados do dia anterior da tabela de movimento

Essa solução 2 achei estranha mas foi indicada por um dba pelo motivo de muitos updates causarem pequenos locks ocasionando perda de performance, já insert não causa Lock

Questionei a respeito do select onde na solução 2 haveria necessidade de fazer um Join com sum e group by sendo que na solução 1 um select simples já resolveria.

Ele me falou que nesse caso um select mais pesado iria onerar menos o banco do que um select simples porém inúmeros updates diários.

O que acham pessoal? Solução 1 ou 2?

Comment: Você está na etapa de modelagem de dados ou na etapa de implementação física do banco de dados?